# How to make User Field Type to be selected Mulitple in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a list definition and I have a field type of User and I want it to be multiple selected. To do that, which property that I should enable if there's any?

```
 <Field ID="{A0372EB5-A947-41CA-A5FA-A34C29D2FB88}"
    Name="Employee"
    DisplayName="Employee"
    Type="User"
    Required="TRUE"
    StaticName="Employee"
    Group="SampleGroup"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put `multi` behind the Type value as
`Type="UserMulti"`. You can also use `UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly"`.
So totally your field value may look like this.

```
<Field ID="{A0372EB5-A947-41CA-A5FA-A34C29D2FB88}"
    Name="Employee"
    DisplayName="Employee"
    Type="UserMulti"
    Required="TRUE"
    StaticName="Employee"
    UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly"
    Group="SampleGroup"/>
```

Find more information in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979575.aspx)

Comment: Thanks mihir. That's what I was looking for. And I want to know, Do I have to add Mult="true" here?

Comment: `Type="UserMulti"` gives you to select multiple members. No need to `set Multi="true"` again...